# How can I delete selected documents in firebase Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

> I have a lot of files in my Firestore that I want to delete through the firebase website but I want to be able to select and delete them instead of deleting them one by one

Answer (score 0):

It could be a hard task to delete many documents on your Firestore instance manually. Specially if you have hundreds or thousands of them. I think the best option would be doing it programmatically through an Application or a Cloud function.

On this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data) you can learn how to implement the delete() method on many popular languages to delete documents, fields, and collections, and on this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections) I found a simple way of creating a Cloud Function while learning how to delete collections.

As a summary there is no easy way to delete many documents,field or collections using the user interface. The best way is to implement code to do it.